# Prevent a command from being executed after another command

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

I would like the shell to warn me for potential errors I'm about to make.

How can I prevent a command `cmd2` from  being executed after `cmd1`.

For example:

```
$ tar tf file.tar
$ rm !$
```

Here, I just forgot that I listed the file instead of extracting its content.

I'm looking for a generic solution, that makes a choice based on the name and return value of the previous command, and on the current command.

Comment: Experience.  Commit that mistake a few times... you'll stop doing it soon, and then you'll commit a different oops.  Wisdom comes from Experience, Experience comes from failure.

Comment: @lornix Thanks for your advice; I'm still looking for a technical solution.

Comment: Adding the `alias rm='rm -i'` command (see @uther below) to your shell startup scripts is the best way.  The computer is not clairvoyant (yet!), and it just follow instructions.  The *best* advice anyone could give is *slow down* and *pay attention* to what you're doing.  Not trying to be snotty or anything.  We've ALL made those mistakes, and likely spent hours cleaning up (or recreating) the mess.  I wouldn't want a computer that held my hand anyways.  I'm in charge, and if I do stupid things, I'm responsible. (did you know you can delete the ENTIRE \Windows subdir while it's running?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking for a lot with a general answer, but it should be possible to do it relatively easily to some extent.

However, `bash` has at least two general mechanisms that can help solve that. You can set the variable PROMPT_COMMAND and this will be executed after anything you run in your prompt:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='echo BOFH says hi!'
BOFH says hi!
$ man man
BOFH says hi!
$
```

We can use this to save the last entered command and then reread it, so we can store it in memory for further use (history expansion does not work in this case):

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; tail -n1 ~/.bash_history'
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; tail -n1 ~/.bash_history'
$ wc < test.sh | grep .
 5 11 63
wc < test.sh | grep .
```

Now comes the logic part, which is completely up to you. Let's use just very simplistic logic to prevent the example in the question. The thing to remember is, that bash functions still work in there, so you don't have to cram everything on a single line, in a single variable.

```
$ # define the logic check
$ checkSanity() { grep -q "tar  *[tf][[:alpha:]]*[tf] " <<< "$@" && echo "be careful, don't delete this"; }
checkSanity() { grep -q "tar  *[tf][[:alpha:]]*[tf] " <<< "$@" && echo "be careful, don't delete this"; }
$ # feed it the last command
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; last=$(tail -n1 ~/.bash_history); checkSanity "$last"'
$ # simple test
$ tar tf test.sh 2>/dev/null 
be careful, don't delete this
$ tar xf test.sh 2>/dev/null 
$
```

Of course, this approach is useful to prevent PEBKAC (especially if you add `sleep 3` at the end), but it can't break the next command on its own.

If that's *really* what you want, trap the `DEBUG` signal (eg. `trap 'echo "I am not deterministic, haha"' DEBUG`), since it runs beforehand. Be careful with combining these two approaches, since the output/action will be doubled:

```
$ df
/.../
$ trap 'tail -n1 ~/.bash_history' DEBUG
df
df
trap 'tail -n1 ~/.bash_history' DEBUG
trap 'tail -n1 ~/.bash_history' DEBUG
```

To make the trap break a command, you'll have to enable `extdebug` (`shopt -s extdebug`). You also don't need to save and reread history constantly, but can inspect `$BASH_COMMAND` to get the command about to be run. Then you just need to make sure the logic checker return 1 when it detects something bad and 0 otherwise.

```
          extdebug
                  If set, behavior intended for use by debuggers is enabled:
    /.../
                  2.     If  the command run by the DEBUG trap returns a non-zero value, the next
                         command is skipped and not executed.


$ checkSanity() { if grep -q "tar  *[tf][[:alpha:]]*[tf] " <<< "$1"; then  echo "be careful, don't delete this"; return 1; fi; }
$ trap 'checkSanity "$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG
$ # simple test
$ tar tf test.sh 2>/dev/null 
be careful, don't delete this
$ tar xf test.sh 2>/dev/null 
$
```

Answer (score 6):

In bash you can set `shopt -s histverify` which would stop the history from being expanded and executed in one step. Here the above `$ rm !$` would expand to `$ rm file.tar` on the first press of <kbd>Enter</kbd>, allowing you to check or edit before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to execute.
A more general solution would veer into ["Do What I Mean"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) territory, requiring a program to second-guess your intentions.

Comment: In this case, it would not be helpful because I almost always expand the !$ directly with TAB; it doesn't remind me that this pattern is probably dangerous.

Comment: This is the only reasonable answer. The brilliant part of the command line is it does what you say without faffing.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you would benefit from error warnings from the `rm` command.

In your shell initialization scripts (assuming `bash`, so `~/.bashrc`), you could alias `rm` to either `-i` or `-I`.

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

From `man 1 rm`

```
   -i     prompt before every removal

   -I     prompt once before removing more than three files, or when
          removing recursively.  Less intrusive than -i, while still
          giving protection against most mistakes
```

The more generic question of, "How do I protect my system from myself" has been [discussed before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42174/what-are-the-recommended-ways-of-defending-a-remote-nix-install-from-a-hamfiste). In a nutshell, *pay attention to what you are doing*, and only run commands as `root` when necessary.

Comment: `rm` was just an example. I'm interested in a more generic solution.

Comment: @Antoine See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, I would do:

```
tar tf file.tar
if [ -f file ]; then   # Assuming you meant to extract a file
  rm -f file.tar
else
  echo "file is missing. Command failed."
fi
```

If you want to check for errors and only run the next command if the first succeeded

```
some_command && another_command
```

Although in your specific case, the second command would still run as it did not error out even though it didn't do what you wanted.